# BrowserWindow.Uri property not updated when .NavigateToUrl(Uri uri) is called

Tags: c#, windows-7, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a Coded UI test method:

```
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    string baseUrl = "www.google.com";
    GlobalVariable.browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(baseUrl));
    GlobalVariable.browser.NavigateToUrl(new System.Uri(baseUrl + "/images"));
    string expected = baseUrl + "/images";
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, GlobalVariable.browser.Uri);
}
```

However, the value of `GlobalVariable.browser.Uri` at the time of the assertion is still pointing to www.google.com, even though the browser was successfully navigated to the expected.  I've tried setting a `Playback.Wait()` to ensure that I'm not asserting too early.  Strangely enough, this only happens on one or two develoment environments (the others show the correct value for `GlobalVariable.browser.Uri`), leading me to believe that there's some environmental variable rather than a code issue.

Also, if, instead of statically setting and updating the GlobalVariable.browser object, we call a `get` function each time we call the object (like so:

```
private BrowserWindow _browser;
public BrowserWindow browser
{
    get
    {
        BrowserWindow currentWindow = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(_browser.Process);
        return currentWindow;
    }
    set 
    {
        _browser = value;
        return _browser;
    }
}
```

), then the object is created based on the system process and has the correct properties. So essentially, the BrowserWindow object created during our initialization method isn't getting updated as it goes along, and we have to create a new object based on the process.  Again, this only occurs on some remote environments and not on the dev machines set up locally. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath it all the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.IEBrowserService which provides both the NavigateToUrl and the Uri get methods delegate their calls to an internal class called InternetExplorerWrapper which is a COM wrapper to a Window Handle. The code internally checks repetedly on a method UpdateWebBrowserReferenceIfInvalid() and recreates the IEBrowserService instance when needeed. Because of this repeated checking, I assume that even the test framework cannot guarantee that the instance of IE that it is dealing with doens't "go away" and need re-connecting with. It depends on the lifetime of the window handle its created out of I guess.

In conclusion, the underlying code repeatedly recreates the IEBrowserService which provides your Uri getter, and it does this in a non-deterministic manner, so by repeating this pattern (creating the browser window on demand)  you are just repeating a pattern that the microsoft guys themselves have used internally.

Comment: I think I follow you, which is why I thought it was silly that getting a new process from the BrowserWindow.GetProcess() works while just calling the object again didn't.  Unless you're suggesting that the former works because that's how Microsoft does it.

Comment: Yes - it seems the code internally expects the connection to IE to be "randomly" unavailable or dropped, and recreates the connection as-required. Its possible therefore that you are seeing a cached URI based on a stale object; if recreating works, then there doesnt seem much harm in recreating the object as you need it.